# Porque las variables de Timepicker me cogen el mismo valor?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, datetimepicker, timepicker

Me gustaría haceros una pregunta: En Android studio con kotlin, porque cuando introduzco una hora en datepicker 1 se me pone en los dos ? Que puedo tener mal? este es mi usuarioActivity:

```
class usuarioActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario)
intextt.setOnClickListener{showDatePickerDialog()}
intextt2.setOnClickListener{showTimePickerDialog()}
outtext.setOnClickListener{showTimePickerDialog()}
}
private fun showTimePickerDialog() {
val timePicker = TimePickerFragment {onTimeSelected(it)}
val timePicker2 = TimePickerFragment{OnTimeSelected2(it)}
timePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "time")
timePicker2.show(supportFragmentManager, "time2")
}
private fun onTimeSelected(time: String) {
intextt2.setText("Ha seleccionado: $time")
}
private fun OnTimeSelected2(time2: String) {
outtext.setText("Ha seleccionado: $time2")
}
```

Luego en TimeFragmentActivity tengo esto:

```
class TimePickerFragment (val listener: (String) -> Unit):DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  {


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        val dialog = TimePickerDialog(activity as Context, this, hour, minute, true)
        return dialog


    }


    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker?, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
    listener("$hourOfDay:$minute")

    }


}
```

Alguien me podria ayudar por favor?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!.

Answer (score -1):

Solucionado! era una respuesta fácil, estaba llamando dos veces a showTimePickerDialog

```
private fun showTimePickerDialog2() {

    val timePicker2 = TimePickerFragment { OnTimeSelected2(it) }

    timePicker2.show(supportFragmentManager, "time2")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. si has encontrado la solición podrias marcarla como resuelta para que pueda servirle a alguien más, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.